# distance between line in cube

Tags: geometry

I am having some problem with highschool mathematic geometry problem. I got the answer but it is not in the multiple choice. I have tried to re-calculate and think it through another perspective. Ultimately, I decide the problem is with my reasoning, but I don't know where I got it wrong.

In the following picture, M is the intersection point of AC and BD while N is the intersection point of HF and EG.

Cube is:

[image]

The problem asked to find the distance between EM and CN. I think ENCM is a parallelogram. So, I calculate the distance by using formula for parallelogram area.

Area = MC x MN = ME x height.

MC = $\frac{7\sqrt2}{2} $

MN = 7

ME = $\frac{7\sqrt6}{2} $

MN is the height of parallelogram when MC is the base. The reason is because MN is perpendicular to AC. Height of parallelogram is the distance between two parallel sides which are EN and MC here.

When ME become the base, distance between CN and EM become the height of parallelogram. I find the answer to be $\frac{7\sqrt3}{3} $. The answers in the multiple choice are :

a. $\frac{7}{2} $

b. 7

c. $\frac{7\sqrt2}{2} $

d. ${7\sqrt2}$

e. ${7\sqrt3}$

Could somebody point out where do I make a mistake? Could it be the textbook make a mistake? Thankyou

Comment: Why should the area of a parallelogram be given by the product of two sides?

Comment: I think you are right, and the book is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$EM = \sqrt{EA^2+AM^2} = \sqrt{7^2+\left(\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{147}{2}}$

The areas of the triangles $NMC$ and $MNE$ are the same. Also $MN=7$ and $MC=\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2}$. That area is $A_T = A_{NMC}+A_{MNE} = 2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot7 = \frac{49\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Now the distance is: $\frac{A_T}{EM} = \frac{49\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{147}} = \frac{7}{\sqrt3}$

There are no answers...

Answer (score 0):

you should compute the area or the $\triangle NEM$, and then to find out the distance from $N$ to $EM$. 
In other words, $NE=\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2}$, $NM=7$, $EM=\frac{7\sqrt{6}}{2}$.

Comment: I tried it, but I ended up with the same answer